# CarrierWave: get attachment owner instance object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

How to Get the Calling Object in Rails?

I have a Part Model, where a Part has a `CarrierWave` attachment Image and an extra column named `prime_pn`.
I need to fetch the image url of the part based on some conditions from `prime_pn`.

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "parts"
    mount_uploader :image_name, ImageNameUploader
end
```

and I have a class named `ImageNameUploader` which is as follows:

```
class ImageNameUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    storage :file

    def store_dir       
     "#{APP_CONFIG['part_image_path']}/#{model.id}"
    end

   def url
    puts __getobj__
   end

   process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]    

  version :thumb do      
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end

  version :small do      
    process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end

 def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end

end
```

In the `url` method of `ImageNameUploader` I need to get the attachment owner, for e.g:

```
Part.find(1).image_name_url #=> "/apps/rails/portal/images/10010/rio.jpg"
```

I need the Part Object in the `url` method , How do I get it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) README:

> The model variable points to the instance object the uploader is
>   attached to.

So `model.prime_pn` should get your required data:

```
class ImageNameUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def url
    prime_pn = model.prime_pn
    # do what ever with it
  end
end
```